# Speed Queen washing machine stopped working mid-cycle

Tags: appliances, washing-machine, washer, laundry

I have a Speed Queen washing machine model AWN432SP111TW01, serial 1110013649.

It's been working fine for years and we had never had any trouble with it, but today it stopped mid-cycle, and won't turn back on.

I tested another device in the same electrical socket and it worked fine. I ran an extension cord from an electrical socket in another room which was working fine and connected the washer to it, but still nothing.

I looked in the user guide troubleshooting section under "Won't Start". I have tried everything there. One of the suggestions there is to give it a few minutes for the motor overload protector to reset; I have given it hours.

The user guide does not mention a fuse in the washer.

I opened up the control panel area of the washer and looked for a fuse but did not find one. There was a sheet in there with a schematic. I scoured it for a fuse but it did not mention one.

I looked all over in there for anything that looked burned or otherwise damaged, or loose, etc. Everything looks as good as new and all connections seem tight.

Any suggestions on what I can try?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the lid switch. On some machines, the lid switch only interrupts the spin cycle. But it may be required to be closed for everything on this machine. The lid switch can fail with little or no warning and should, ideally, fail open rather than closed.

Comment: I tried shorting out the lid switch and that made it work. So I believe I have a bad lid switch.